# adding a class to an element after clicking a button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, navbar

I have got a responsive joomla page with bootstrap.
When I click on the button for the mobile menu (class="navbar-toggle") I would like to extend it and show the li-element (".item-259") wich contains a dropdown-menu already opened, by adding the class "open".

I don't know why this code isn't working, but the class "open" is not added to li.item-259, when I click on the button and it shows the menu...

Does anybody know whats wrong with it?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery('.navbar-toggle').on('click',function(){
    jQuery('.item-259').addClass('open');
});
</script>
```

Edit: that is the html... thanks for your fast help

```
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">    <!-- =MOBILE -->

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hauptnavigation" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Hauptmenü ausklappen</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>


                    <a class="navbar-brand" title="zur Startseite" href="/index.php">                                          
                        <img class="logo" src="..." alt="Logo" />
                    </a>

                </div><!-- navbar-header -->

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="hauptnavigation">
                    <nav>
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" />
                    </nav>  
                </div><!-- navbar-collapse -->

            </nav>
        </div><!-- container -->
```

It is so weird... this also isn't working:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.navbar-toggle').on('click',function(){
        jQuery('.item-259').addClass('open');
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

BUT this is working:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(document).on('click',function(){
        jQuery('.item-259').addClass('open');
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Problem with that is, that my submenu opens on every click on the document (everywhere) if it is not the mobile version...

Comment: you should wrap the code in DOM ready.

Comment: Could you please post the related HTML markup also. That would help greatly!

Comment: Never use [bootstrap] as tag, use [twitter-bootstrap] instead. Try hovering your mouse on the tag to get more info.

Comment: This very vanilla fiddle shows that it works. You may want to check something else. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/4n89xj41/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

```
jQuery('.navbar-toggle').on('click',function(){
    jQuery('.item-259').addClass('open');
    });
```

});

or

```
    jQuery('.navbar-toggle').live('click',function(){
        jQuery('.item-259').addClass('open');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all should the code stay between:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Maybe the Element isn't described well as CSS selector, but without HTML code or similiar I can't say it exactly.